# What is the word for the place/address a person lived, or is identified with, most of their lives?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know this word exists but I can't remember it. It is like saying current address or last address but has the meaning of the address a person lived most of their lives or is identified with most.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: *Domicile:* place of usual residence; *Native:* place of birth;

Comment: ... long-time home.

Comment: Hometown: The town or city of one's birth, rearing, or main residence.

Comment: In asking a question one might say "What do you consider home?"

Answer (score 3):

Might seem a bit obvious, but it **is** the best term.

[Home](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/home#Noun)

> 1.3. The abiding place of the affections, especially of the domestic affections.
>
> 3. The locality where a thing is usually found, or was first found, or where it is naturally abundant

A person's home is the place they identify with most.

Now, if you're writing a form (i.e. a tax form) and you want the place the person has most often lived *recently*, you'd say the ["primary residence"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_residence).